# In Perforce, how can I check in a file previously checked out on another machine/workspace?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I hope I'm not asking a question that's already been answered, but I can't seem to find one that fits my situation.

**Scenario**:  Using P4V gui (2011 version), with no access to P4 command line, on Windows 7.

**The setup**:  A user creates a workspace in Perforce from Machine A, pointing that workspace to a shared network drive, and checks out a file for editing.

Machine A then dies before the user can check in the file.  The user is then assigned Machine B, for which he must create a new workspace (which is also pointed at the same shared network drive).

**The problem**:  The problem we're having is that even though the workspace from the dead Machine A and from the new Machine B both point to the same location, Perforce considers them to be different workspaces and prevents the user from checking in/submitting the previously checked out file.

Any suggestions on how to check in this stranded file would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing out the Host field? For example, see 'Using the same workspace from different machines':

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.configuration.html#d0e1720

As an update from my comment response, if you need to change ownership of a changelist, the steps are documented here:

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Changing-the-Owner-of-a-Pending-Changelist

Comment: Hi P4Shimada - Thanks for the reply.  Yes, that allowed me to see the file in the original workspace, but it's marked with a blue checkmark, not red, as if it was checked out by another user.  Right-clicking on the file doesn't give me the option to "submit" - it gives me a list of options as if it's not yet checked out.  I'm wondering if I need to try to get access to the command line which may give me more options?

Comment: There may be a blue check-mark to indicate the file is checked out by the other workspace. To change ownership of a changelist, do the following: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Changing-the-Owner-of-a-Pending-Changelist

Comment: Hi P4Shimada, Thank you again for your suggestions.  From what I can tell from your references, I would need to have access to the original machine in order to revert or otherwise transfer ownership.  However, the machine is dead and I cannot get it back.  I found that I do actually have access to the P4 command line, so I'm going to investigate whether there are additional options available via the CL that aren't provided with P4V.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Vrin. You're welcome. To transfer the file via Perforce the file would have had to be shelved where it was pending on the server. Otherwise, you would need the original machine to retrieve it since pending changes are on each individual client workstation machine - unless they are shelved. However a user with admin or super rights in Perforce CAN REVERT the files as outlined here: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Reverting-Another-User-s-Files

Comment: Thanks @P4Shimada, this is what I suspected.  Looks like I'm stuck unless I can figure out who our "superuser" is in our IT group - they don't like to tell us for fear we might ask them to do things.  :)  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To be nice and clean, I'd suggest this:

1. **Make a backup copy of the file as it exists on the shared network drive.**
2. Connect to the depot from Workspace A (can be done from Machine B if the workspace isn't bound to Machine A).
3. Revert the file - this will overwrite the file on the drive with the version in the depot (aren't you glad you made a copy first?).
4. Switch to Workspace B.
5. Check out the file.
6. Copy the backup version over the file on the shared network drive.
7. Check in the file.

...and if you're not planning on using Workspace A anymore, I'd suggest deleting it.

Comment: Hi Mark - Thanks so much for your reply.  I don't know how to check if a workspace is bound to a machine?  I'm fairly new at Perforce and don't have access to the command line which is fairly limiting.  I'll do a Google search on this but if you have any suggestions I'd greatly appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: The Host: field in the workspace is what binds it to a machine. You can clear this field out. See these references here: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Client-can-only-be-used-from-host  http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.configuration.html#d0e1720